# Использование оператора case в SQLite

Tags: sqlite

Я написал запрос для вычисления процентного соотношения количества строк [country] минус 1 к общему количеству этих строк. Также если при выборе существуют строки [cc] со значениями WO, EP, EA, OA, AP, GC -- [prc] должно принимать значение [100%].
Таблица формируется так:

```
       CREATE TABLE [patent_country] (
  [id_patent_country] INTEGER NOT NULL PRIMARY KEY AUTOINCREMENT, 
  [id_patent] INTEGER, 
  [country] VARCHAR,
  [cc] VARCHAR)

  INSERT INTO patent_country (id_patent, country, cc)
  VALUES (1,    'DE',   'AU');
  INSERT INTO patent_country (id_patent, country, cc)
  VALUES (2,    'AU',   'AU');
  INSERT INTO patent_country (id_patent, country, cc)
  VALUES (2,    'DE',   'AU');
  INSERT INTO patent_country (id_patent, country, cc)
  VALUES (2,    'WO',   'AU');
  INSERT INTO patent_country (id_patent, country, cc)
  VALUES (3,    'DE',   'AU');
  INSERT INTO patent_country (id_patent, country, cc)
  VALUES (4,    'RU',   'AU');
  INSERT INTO patent_country (id_patent, country, cc)
  VALUES (5,    'RU',   'AU');
  INSERT INTO patent_country (id_patent, country, cc)
  VALUES (6,    'RU',   'AU');
  INSERT INTO patent_country (id_patent, country, cc)
  VALUES (7,    'RU',   'AU');
  INSERT INTO patent_country (id_patent, country, cc)
  VALUES (8,    'AU',   'WO');
  INSERT INTO patent_country (id_patent, country, cc)
  VALUES (9,    'CN',   'WO');
  INSERT INTO patent_country (id_patent, country, cc)
  VALUES (9,    'DE',   'WO');
  INSERT INTO patent_country (id_patent, country, cc)
  VALUES (9,    'DK',   'WO');
  INSERT INTO patent_country (id_patent, country, cc)
  VALUES (9,    'EP',   'WO');
```

Запрос:

```
select  cc,
        case 
            when cc = 'WO' 
            then '100%'
            when cc = 'EP' 
            then '100%'
            when cc = 'EA' 
            then '100%'
            when cc = 'OA' 
            then '100%'
            when cc = 'AP' 
            then '100%'
            when cc = 'GC' 
            then '100%'
            else (count(country) - 1)/count(country) || ' ' || '%'
            end as prc
        from patent_country
group by cc
```

***Никак не могу выражение (count(country) - 1)/count(country) умножить на 100 и округлить до первого знака после запятой.*** 
Результат моего запроса выглядит так :

```
| cc       |   prc    |
 ---------------------|
| AU       | 0,88888  |
 ---------------------|
| WO       | 100 %    |
 ---------------------|
| OA       | 100 %    |
 ---------------------|
| EP       | 100 %    |
 ---------------------

Нужно чтобы было так:

| cc       |   prc    |
 ---------------------|
| AU       | 88,8 %   |
 ---------------------|
| WO       | 100 %    |
 ---------------------|
| OA       | 100 %    |
 ---------------------|
| EP       | 100 %    |
 ---------------------
```

Comment: А какое отношение ваш вопрос имеет к case, если он об округлении которое работает одинаково где бы оно ни было в case или само по себе. И используется для этого функция `round()` http://www.w3resource.com/sqlite/core-functions-round.php  А что касается вашего case, то запись вида `case 
            when cc IN('WO','EP','EA',...) then '100%'` выглядела бы короче

Comment: @Mike Спасибо за подсказку. Сделал запрос короче. 'select cc,
  case 
   when cc IN ('WO', 'EP', 'EA', 'OA', 'AP', 'GC')
   then '100%'
                        when cc = country
   then round((100.0 * count(country)/(count(cc) - 1)-100),1) || ' %'
   else round((100.0 * (count(country) - 1)/ count(country)),1) || ' %'
   end as prc
  from patent_country
group by cc;'

Comment: @Mike  Я не учёл момент, когда ячейки [cc] и [country] совпадают. И ещё не учёл, когда в группе могут быть совпадающий один [cc] и [country], в этом случае [prc] должен быть 0. А если одиночные [cc] и [country] не совпадают, тогда [prc] должен быть 100.Надо как-то из [count(country)] вычитать совпадающие [cc], далее делить на count(cc) и умножать на 100. Можно ли перезаписать таблицу [patent_country], сгруппировав [group by cc], и заменив ячейки в [country] на NULL, а потом использовать [where (country is not null)] для подсчёта [count(country)].